# Wordpress file download byte-order-mark

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress online shop with Woocommerce.
In the Dashboard I have a plugin which allows me to export more invoices at once.
The export operation generates a zip archive and then opens a download popup.
When downloading the zip archive like this it is corrupt.
The corrupt file that is sent via the download function has the 3 bytes of the UTF-8 byte-order-mark appended at the start (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF).

When downloading the file via FTP it is working. This means the zip archive is okay, but the download is changing it with the header.

Comment: the BOM probably exists in the file serving the download, you need to remove that

Comment: @rtfm do you mean the php file creating the .zip archive and open the download popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the wp-config.php had the UTF-8 byte-order-mark. I removed it and now the zip archive is okay.